# How do I change the color of the content inside window showed in the image? I'm using STS

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I was using STS and decided to give it a try to the dark theme, but the color of the tooltip window, was black and the font also black hence impossible to read, so I restored the appearance to the default settings hoping that the tooltip window color would change as well but it didn't. I haven't found a way to customize the colors of it. Does anyone knows how to do that? Thanks in advance.

[screenshot of tooltip window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgSSZ.png)

Comment: Did you restart STS ?

Comment: @rdj7 yes, that worked! Thanks!

Comment: nice to hear that, great :)